# What is the difference between (take 5 (range)) and (range 5)

Tags: clojure

I'm just starting to learn Clojure and I've seen several uses of the 'take' function in reference to range.

Specifically

```
(take 5 (range))
```

Which seems identical to

```
(range 5)
```

Both Generate

```
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

Is there a reason either stylistically or for performance to use one or the other?

Comment: Perhaps the authors just wanted to illustrate the use of `take`.  Passing `(range)` to provides a very simple illustration.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, using `(range 5)` is likely to be more performant and I would consider it more idiomatic. However, keep in mind that this requires one to know the extent of the range at the time of its creation.

In cases where the size is unknown initially, or some other transformation may take place after construction, having the `take` option is quite nice. For example:

```
(->> (range) (filter even?) (drop 1) (take 5))
```

Comment: Note also that take (and others) can also be used as a transducer which appears similar to the above code: (sequence (comp (filter even?) (drop 1) (take 5)) (range)) but can be used in a wider variety of situations. For example the (comp (filter even?) (drop 1) (take 5)) transducer could be used to process a stream of values in the core.async api.

Answer (score 3):

Both have the same performance. Because (range) function is returning a lazy seq, not yet realized till access the elements. According to Danial Higginbotham in his book "Clojure for the brave and true" The lazy sequence 
  consists of two parts: a recipe for how to realize the elements of a sequence and the elements have been realized so far. When you are using (range) it doesn't include any realized elements
  but it does have the recipe for generating its elements. everytime you try to access an unrealized elements the lazy seq will use its recipe to generate the requested element.

here is the link that explains the lazy seq in depth
http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/

Answer (score 1):

Range can be used in following forms

```
(range) #or
(range end) #or
(range start end) #or
(range start end step)
```

So here you have control over the range you are generating and you are generating collection
in your example using (range) will give a lazy sequence which will be evaluated as per the need so you take function needs 5 items so those many items are generated

While take is used like

```
(take n) #or
(take n coll)
```

where you need to pass the collection from which you want to take n items